# Delete password edit field in spatie/laravel-permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

[image]

I'm using **spatie/laravel-permission** package for permission system.
but I want to use it except for the password edit field.
where could I have to modify to make it?
other way, could I edit role without entering a password field?

Comment: Maybe make 3 diffenrent forms on edit page. One for details, one for roles, and one for password. so you should make 3 different routes and menthods in controller

Answer (score 0):

This is self answer.

Delete password check in validate() where update() in UserController.

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'=>'required|max:120',
        'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
        // 'password'=>'required|min:6|confirmed'
    ]);
```